# Windows sample driver builds properly but will not install,

Tags: windows, installation, driver, wdf

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, since its technically not a programming question, but it conecerns driver development so anyway:

For a school assignment I have to take a look at the code of a WDF sample driver. (And change it a little bit) So I downloaded the Windows Driver Kit, and tried to build an example driver. (Ramdisk sample driver)

The build goes fine, but when I try to install it using the add new hardware wizard it fails while installing. The wizard tells me it "cannot find the file specified". I tried other example drivers, tried on different machines, etc,... It always gives the same error. (I followed the documentation exactly for building and installation)

Answer (score 3):

I found it. When I installed using "DEVCON.EXE INSTALL ramdisk.inf ramdisk" it generates a log file @ %windir%\inf\setupapi.dev.log There I found that it was missing the WdfCoInstaller01009.dll. Just copied that from the redist folder of the DDK and it installed fine.